# Bootstrap website is scrollable to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Me and my friends are currently trying to develop a bootstrap based website for a project our school is part of.

Everything went fine and our site is live, view on tablet is OK, viem on mobile landscape is ok but mobile portrait is bad..

http://www.sosklobouky.cz/DIKYPR/index.html

Text in jumbotron is outside of the jumbotron and i would like to ask how should i repair it ?

Should i target devices @media (max-width:767px;) or should i do it another way ?

Thanks again !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DIKYPR - MěSOŠ</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/vendor/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href="STYLE.CSS" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
    <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/flat-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!--ikonka v záložce-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/klobouk.png">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements. All other JS at the end of file. -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <!--NAVIGACE-->
      <header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">DIKYPR</a><!--logo-->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-01"><!--responzivnost-->
            <span class="sr-only">Navigace</span>
          </button>        
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01" id="navbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-loc="home">DOMŮ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#obsah" data-loc="obsah">OBSAH</a></li>
                <li><a href="skoleni.html" data-loc="skoleni">ŠKOLENÍ</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">AKTIVITY<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="aktivity.html#odkaz1">KOUČINK, MENTORING A PODPORA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aktivity.html#odkaz2">VZDĚLÁNÍ K INTEGRACI ICT DO VÝUKY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aktivity.html#odkaz3">EVALUACE</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="kestazeni.html">KE STAŽENÍ</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </header>


    <section id="home" class="scroll-panel">
   <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 align="center">Didaktika pro kyberprostor</h1>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <p class="text-left">Operační program<br>Vzdělávání pro konkurence schopnost</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="text-right">Registrační číslo projektu<br>CZ.1.07/1.3.00/51.0027</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--row-->
        <div class="row" align="center">
                <img src="img/lenovo.png" class="img-responsive" align="center">
         </div>   
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="text-left">Městská střední odborná škola,<br>Klobouky u Brna nám. Míru 6,<br>příspěvková organizace</p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="text-right">nám. Míru 6 č. p. 101,<br>Klobouky u Brna,<br>PSČ 691 72</p>
            </div>    
        </div><!--row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                <a href="#obsah" data-loc="obsah">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-lg">CHCI SE DOZVĚDĚT VÍC</button>
                </a>
            </div><!--colmd12-->    
        </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--ukončuje container-->
        </div><!--JUMBOTRON-->
    </section>

<section id="obsah" class="scroll-panel">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <br> 
           <h1 align="center" class="nadpis2">Popis projektu</h1>
        </div><!--row-->
        <div class="row">
            <p class="text-justify">Obsah projektu připravujeme v&nbsp;souladu Výzvou k&nbsp;předkládání žádostí individuálních projektů OP Vzdělávání pro konkurenceschopnost, Oblast podpory 1.3 - Další vzdělávání pracovníků škol 
a&nbsp;školských zařízení.<br>
Zdůvodnění Výzvy, a&nbsp;její Metodický výklad, jasně ukazují, že i&nbsp;přes významné investice vynaložené v&nbsp;oblasti ICT našich škol nejsou přínosy a&nbsp;efektivnost využívání dostupných zařízení na očekávané výši.<br>
Naše společnost je zaměřena na dodávky informačních systémů a&nbsp;víme, co to pro efektivnost vynaložené investice znamená umět jí využívat. Proto jsme se v&nbsp;posledních létech výrazně orientovali na znalosti a&nbsp;dovednosti uživatelů a&nbsp;na metody vzdělávání. Cílům projektu rozumíme, ztotožňujeme ses nimi, a&nbsp;věříme, že zvolenou metodou individuálních projektů lze očekávaných cílů dosáhnout.<br>
Podstatu projektu nespatřujeme v&nbsp;dotykových zařízeních, ta jsou jen okrajovou investicí. 
Za stěžejní považujeme metody, jak efektivně využít dostupná zařízení. Od toho se také odvíjí  
i&nbsp;název našeho projektu.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!--ukončuje container-->
    </section>
    <hr class="divider"><!--oddělovač-->


    <!---------AKTIVITY------->
   <section>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <center>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h6>Koučink, mentoring a podpora pedagogických pracovníků</h6>
            <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="aktivity.html#odkaz1" role="button">VÍCE »</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h6>Vzdělávání pedagogických pracovníků k integraci ICT<br>do výuky</h6>
            <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="aktivity.html#odkaz2" role="button">VÍCE »</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h6 class="evaluace">Evaluace</h6>
            <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="aktivity.html#odkaz3" role="button">VÍCE »</a></p>
         </center>
        </div><!--ukončuje colmd4-->
      </div><!--ukončuje row-->
    </div><!--ukončuje container-->


       <!--řádek se sponzory-->
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row" align="center" id="paticka">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img src="img/EU.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div><!--ukončí container--> 

         </section>
      <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted credit" align="center">© 2014  Mičulka Martin, Ivan Ondřej, Havlík Ondřej</p>
        </div>
    </div> 





    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Flat UI's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script> 
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});

       </script>

  </body>
</html>




body {
    font-family: 'roboto_slabregular';
}
#nadpis {
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#operprog, #regcislo {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#nadpis1 {
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#napis11{
    margin-top: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#odstavce {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nadpis2 {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#odstavec1{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.evaluace {
    padding-top: 18px;
}

#mezera{
    padding-top: 150px;
}

#paticka {
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide all essential code in your question and not through a live link. Thank you!

Comment: im very sorry, im so confused about it i completely forgot about the main thing ! its edited tho !

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line of code below to your body css code

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```